# "Weakly" linearly dependent distributions (generalised functions) implies linearly dependent

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, linear-transformations, distribution-theory

Consider distributions (generalised functions) with compact support $u_{ij} \in \mathcal{E}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for $1 \leq i, j \leq m$. Write $u_i = (u_{1i}, u_{2i}, \dotso, u_{mi})$ for the column vectors determined by $u_{ij}$ (vector valued distributions). Say $u_1, \dotso, u_m$ are *weakly linearly dependent* (WLD) if
$$\det(u_{ij}(f)) = 0, \quad \mathrm{for \,\, all} \quad f \in C_0^\infty(\Omega).$$

Question: does WLD imply that $u_1, \dotso, u_m$ are linearly dependent? Hints toward references also greatly appreciated.

EDIT 2: the question as stated is clearly false: just take distributions with disjoint supports to see it's false. Thus it's natural to assume the supports of $u_{ij}$ are the same. However, then if we take n = 1 and 
$$u_{11} = \delta_0',\,\, u_{21} = \delta_0',\,\, u_{12} = \delta_0, \,\,u_{22} = \delta_0,$$
then $u_1$ and $u_2$ are WLD, but not LD (rows are LD, though). So the reasonable test case and a new question seems to be

Question: let $m = 2$, $u_1$ and $u_2$ have equal supports and are WLD. Then either $u_1$ is obtained by applying a constant coefficient diff op to $u_2$ or we obtain $u_2$ from $u_1$ in a similar way; OR we can say the same for rows.

This seems to be true for $n = 1$ and distributions supported at a point.

Comment: What do you mean with for example $u_{11} u_{22} - u_{12} u_{21} = \delta_0' \delta_0 - \delta_0' \delta_0$? The product $\delta_0' \delta_0$ is not welldefined. Should it be a tensor product $\delta_0' \otimes \delta_0 \in \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb R^{2n})$?

Comment: The definition of WLD doesn't involve any distributional products, so it's enough to note in my example that $\delta'_0(f) \delta_0(f) - \delta'_0(f) \delta_0(f) = f'(0)f(0) - f'(0) f(0) = 0$, to say that $u_1$ and $u_2$ are WLD.